# how to ReactDOM.render into createRoot?

Tags: reactjs, components

> Warning: ReactDOM.render is no longer supported in React 18. Use createRoot instead. Until you switch to the new API, your app will behave as if it's running React 17. Learn more: https://reactjs.org/link/switch-to-createroot

Answer (score 0):

Use instead:

```js
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
const container = document.getElementById('app');
const root = createRoot(container);
root.render(<App tab="home" />);
```

Comment: simple code replace kr ka dahka dae plz?

Comment: Where is your code?